# Inject variables of parent context in function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm developing a micro MV* Framework for JavaScript and came upon the idea to introduce computed properties like it's done in Ember.js

What I basically want is something like this:

```
_defaults: {
    firstEarning: 5,
    secondEarning: 1200.75,
    paycheck: function(firstEarning, secondEarning) {
        return firstEarning + secondEarning;
    }.inject('firstEarning', 'secondEarning')
}
```

When I want to retrieve `paycheck` then the values of `firstEarning` and `secondEarning` should be injected into the function.

I tried to extend the Function prototype, but realized that I don't have the context pointing to the object where `_defaults` lives.

I tried to understand what Ember.js did to achieve this, but I didn't really get it.

Has anybody here an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I think you're really over-thinking this.

Just use `this`:

```
_defaults: {
    firstEarning: 5,
    secondEarning: 1200.75,
    paycheck: function() {
        return this.firstEarning + this.secondEarning;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh... of course. I'll use that. But despite that, I would really be interested in the solution of Ember.js and how they get the original context.